# How to validate certain element of object created inside the LinkedList

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list

My current task is to create Linked List with Clock objects in it. Furthermore, I have to create a method that will add one minute to each clock inside the Linked List.

There is one thing I thought about and I would like to add to this task as my idea - i called it validator. I want it to validate if there is 60 minutes on the clock, so it will change hour and minutes after adding this one minute.

I tried to create diffrent methods and if variations. I ran out of any ideas.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.time.*;

class Clock {
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;

    public Clock (int hours, int minutes){
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }
    public  int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }
    public int getMinutes(){
        return minutes;
    }
    public int addOneMinute(){
        return minutes = minutes + 1;
    }
    public int hoursSwapper(){
        return (hours = hours + 1);
    }
    public int minutesSwapper() {
        return (minutes = 00);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Clock time is " + hours + "." + minutes;
    }
}
class Program{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws java.lang.Exception{

    Random hoursGenerator = new Random();
    Random minutesGenerator = new Random();

    Clock clock0 = new Clock(hoursGenerator.nextInt(24), minutesGenerator.nextInt(60));
    Clock clock1 = new Clock(hoursGenerator.nextInt(24), minutesGenerator.nextInt(60));
    Clock clock2 = new Clock(hoursGenerator.nextInt(24), minutesGenerator.nextInt(60));
    Clock clock3 = new Clock(hoursGenerator.nextInt(24), minutesGenerator.nextInt(60));
    Clock clock4 = new Clock(hoursGenerator.nextInt(24), minutesGenerator.nextInt(60));

        LinkedList<Clock> clockCollection = new LinkedList<Clock>();
        clockCollection.add(clock0);
        clockCollection.add(clock1);
        clockCollection.add(clock2);
        clockCollection.add(clock3);
        clockCollection.add(clock4);

        for (int j = 0; j < clockCollection.size(); j ++){
            System.out.println(clockCollection.get(j));
            clockCollection.get(j).addOneMinute();
            System.out.println(clockCollection.get(j));
            if (clockCollection.get(j) == 60) {

            }
            System.out.println(clockCollection.get(j));
            System.out.println("---");
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make the code upgrade na system.out hour IF there would be 60 minutes (raise hour and reset minutes to 00).

Comment: Why not just add an `if` condition in your `addOneMinute` method that sets the value back to 00 and adds 1 to the hour when it hits 60?

Comment: Uhm...Could you please explain your idea a little?

Comment: Here is my point - you shouldn't have the check to ensure it doesn't roll to 61 in a static method.  It should be handled inside of the object's class to ensure the code can be reused easily.  The check should be done in any method the adds minutes, which is only one in your case - `addOneMinute`

Comment: Yes, and you can even make it a private method inside of the class that you call like : `minutes = minutes + 1` then `checkMinutes()` that does the condition for you so you don't have to always rewrite it.

Comment: I wrote it out to explain it better.

Comment: Why even bother with hours variable? Why not express everything in minutes-past-midnight? This will make the math far easier

Comment: I have to follow the task. One of the parts is to create hours and minutes private values for Clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a private method `checkMinutes()` that you will call inside of the `Clock` class every time you add minutes in one of the class's methods (for example if you made an `addFiveMinutes()`.

```
public int addOneMinute(){
    minutes++;
    checkMinutes();
}

private void checkMinutes(){
    if (minutes >= 60)
    {
        hours++;
        minutes = minutes - 60; 
    }
}

//Having the private check method makes it simple to expand functionality in the future like so
public int addFiveMinutes(){
    minutes = minutes + 5;
    checkMinutes();
}
```

This will ensure the time rollovers to the correct amount as well, for example if minutes is 65 then the new minutes will be 5.

Now every time you call `addOneMinute()` in your main method, you don't have to check for anything! It will all be done automatically every single time.

Comment: It's done. Thank you. Completly forgot about making void method (so it has not to return a value) instead of int method that HAS TO return a value :)

Comment: Its okay we all start somewhere.  More importantly try to remember to take advantage of the Object Oriented aspect of Java and reuse code as much as possible and limit code in `static` methods as much as possible!

Comment: I try to! This code I have written this code with only a little complications after a month of hard work (I am learning Java for at least 3 hours a day, in weekend i reach to 8-9 hours)